# Can a kohen have a child by IVF with a divorce. What is the status of the child?

Tags: kohen-priest, medicine, divorce, contemporary-halacha

Is there any workaround avialable for thousands of kohanim who want to have children but are older singles and can't get married because of the high percentage of divorcees in the female population near their age? Can they give up their kehuna to have a child? Could they father a child through IVF (in vitro fertilization) with a divorcee (concentrating on the specific halachic ramifications of this part of the question)?

Comment: It is not possible to renounce one's kehunah.

Comment: Is it possible for him to adopt?

Comment: Backtrack the question one step. Can a yisroel impregnate a women he’s not married to via IVF?